# How do you call a list using a variable in Python?

Tags: python, list, variables, call

I'm trying to call a list within a function, but the problem is I need hundreds of lists to be called and effected. I can't think of a way to do this without raising a **TypeError** or **NameError**

Comment: ...sounds like iteration. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you ask a question you should try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we all have examples of your data, and/or things you have already tried.

Comment: We don't know what you mean when you want to "call" or "effect" a list.  In Python terms, you *call* a function, not a data structure; "effect" is not a specific programming term.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason you can't call hundreds of lists within a function.

```
def list_manager(list_of_lists):
    for item in list_of_lists:
        # do anything you want with your list here
```